# How to send an email with an attachment via outlook programmatically?

Tags: winapi, outlook, ole, office-automation, new-outlook

My app starts an outlook and send an email with an attachment. My new pc has a different version of outlook, The version is 1.2023.1018.300 (Production). Client Version is 20231013005.12 .

My app get an error with the new outlook. The error message is "Invalid class string".

The error is from starting an outlook process by using ole.

````
     ``` Outlook:=CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application') ;```
````

I guess the new outlook has a different name.

I tried using ShellExecute as well. This way launches outlook without error, but it doesn't have an attachment in the email.

````
``` ShellExecute(handle, "open", em_mail, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);```
````

The em_mail is 'mailto:' & recipient_email_address & '?subject=' & subject & '&body=' & body & '&attachment=' & attachment_path;

Thanks for your help.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Outlook (Monarch) does not have the same COM API as the desktop Outlook. It does not have any API besides Web addins (JS).